# Deploy Vault architecture with Terraform

Tags: terraform, vault

I'm trying to deploy a Vault architecture with Terraform but I get stuck on the loops

I can't create a loop able to deploy my resources from my .json file

The loop should iterate over each "config" to make it a resource and then create empty secrets with their respective names

Here is my main.tf :

```
locals {
    all_data = jsondecode(file("data.json"))
    config = local.all_data.Config

}

resource "vault_mount" "staging" {
    path = "staging"
    type = "kv-v2"
    description = "Staging environment secrets"  
}


resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "config" {
  
    for_each = toset(local.config)

    mount                      = vault_mount.staging.path
    name                       = each.key
    cas                        = 1
    delete_all_versions        = true

    data_json                  = jsonencode(
    {
      (each.value.NAME) = ""
      
    }
    )

}
```

And the .json for the data:

```json
{"Config" : [
    {"Config/partoo" : {
        "NAME" : ["apiKey"]
    }},
    {"Config/toucan" : {
        "NAME" : ["embedErId", "embedSlmId"]
    }},
    {"Config/hubspot" : {
        "NAME" :["clientId", "clientSecret"]
    }}, 
    {"Config/sendGrid" : {
        "NAME" :["key"]
    }}
    
]

}
```

Comment: Are there any errors? If so, please add that to the question as well.

Comment: I'm just trying to deploy the architecture but I can't find enough information so I ask if anyone knows how to do. The solution I propose doesn't work but this is all I could find

Comment: Vault architecture primarily involves instances and networking. Those both appear to be absent from the config.